# How to authenticate an user in ActiveDirectory with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, authentication

I would like to authenticate an user in my ActiveDirectory with the Username and the Password. Is there any chance to do that with powershell and the activeDirectory module. 
Thank you

Comment: Such questions with no details and no hint of what you have tried ( and failed ) are not welcome in StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you need to validate user credentials against active directory?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Next time I gonna write my question more in detail

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Here is a quick and simple function which authenticates a user to AD.

```
Function Test-ADAuthentication {
    param($username,$password)
    (new-object directoryservices.directoryentry "",$username,$password).psbase.name -ne $null
}

PS C:\> Test-ADAuthentication "dom\myusername" "mypassword"
True
PS C:\>
```

It might not be the best function for your needs but your question lacks details.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank You and sorry for the lack of details. Next time I gonna write my question more in detail

Comment: At least this solution does not work for me, while the answer from @Shay Levy works like a miracle !

Answer (score 19):

Requires .NET 3.5 and PowerShell V2

```
$UserName = 'user1'
$Password = 'P@ssw0rd'
$Domain = $env:USERDOMAIN

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$pc = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext $ct,$Domain
$pc.ValidateCredentials($UserName,$Password)
```

Comment: The solution stands the test of time, after 12+ years! Sincere salutation to you, Shay !

Answer (score 0):

here is my version of the script.
In this vesion the credentials are not stored in plain text,
when you run the function it will prompt you to enter the credentials and

Function Test-ADAuthentication {
$Cred = Get-Credential
(New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry "",$($Cred.UserName),$($cred.GetNetworkCredential().password)).psbase.name -ne $null
}

If pass is wrong return false, if pass is right return true

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).